# Repeat id of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm still learning, so I'm racking my brain.

```
$('.post-outer .post-footer .post-footer-line.post-footer-line-2 .post-labels a').each(function(index, el) {
     $('.post-outer').attr('itemtype', $(this).attr('href') );
});
```

When you run the JS above it only takes the first "href" repeating in other "DIV". What is going on:

```
<div class="post-outer" id="001" itemtype="url1">test1</div>
<div class="post-outer" id="002" itemtype="url1">test2</div>
<div class="post-outer" id="003" itemtype="url1">test3</div>
```

I wanted to happen this:

```
<div class="post-outer" id="001" itemtype="url1">test1</div>
<div class="post-outer" id="002" itemtype="url2">test2</div>
<div class="post-outer" id="003" itemtype="url3">test3</div>
```

Here in the example it just takes the last div and repeated in other
https://jsfiddle.net/mpb9wfmc/

Comment: can you add your html code ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mpb9wfmc/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mpb9wfmc/2/   here is it

Comment: I was just that I was trying! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using `.each` you can use `this` for the current element be iterated though:

```
$(this).attr('itemtype', newValueHere );
```

Doing `$('.post-outer').attr('itemtype', $(this).attr('href') );` will apply it to all items with the class `post-outer`.

Comment: but how can I make of it? https://jsfiddle.net/mpb9wfmc/

Comment: @MateusBatista You just need to do `$(this).attr('itemtype', $(this).attr('href') );`. [Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpb9wfmc/3/).